# Vuejs checkbox child state not updating

Tags: checkbox, vuejs2, element-ui

I'm a beginner in Vue.js and I'm stuck at this:

```html
<span>Condition</span>
<el-select style="width: 94%;" v-model="condition[index+1]">
  <el-option label="Ambient" value="Ambient">Ambient</el-option>
  <el-option label="Frozen" value="Frozen">Frozen</el-option>
</el-select>
<h4>
  <el-checkbox v-model="check[index+1]" @change="selectAllPanels(index+1, item.id)">Select All</el-checkbox>
</h4>
<div class="card-content panels-category" v-for="(category, n) in panelsCategory[item.id]" :key="category.id" style="float: left">
  <div class="panel-category" v-if="searchList[item.id][n].length > 0">
    <el-checkbox v-model="checkAll[index+1][item.id][n]" @change="checkAllPanel(index+1, item.id, n)"  :label="category.id" :key="category.id">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{ category[0].panel_category }}</h5>
    </el-checkbox>
  </div>
  <div class="panels" v-for="panels in searchList[item.id][n]" :key="panels.id">     <!-- in panelsCategory[item.id][n]-->
    <!--<el-checkbox-group class="panels-name" v-model="selectedPanels[index+1][item.id]"  @change="handelAddSample(index+1)">-->
      <el-checkbox :checked="checkAll[index+1][item.id][n]" class="panels-name" v-model="selectedPanels[index+1][item.id]"  @change="handelAddSample()" :label="panels.id" :key="panels.id" >{{panels.reportable_name}}</el-checkbox>
      <el-popover class="panel-popover"
                  trigger="hover"
                  @show="getPanelTest(panels.id)"
                  placement="bottom">
        <el-button slot="reference" class="ti-help popover-help"></el-button>
        <slot>{{panelTest}}</slot>
      </el-popover>
    <!--</el-checkbox-group>-->
  </div>
  <div class="panels" v-if="searchList[item.id][n].length > 0" v-for="i in getPanelsLength(index+1, item.id, n)" ></div>
</div>
```

At click on plus button from the right side-->click sth from the dropdown list-->it displays the new tab

So, here, in these tabs comes the magic: the checkboxes are not working well, I mean at click on "Select All" checkbox, all checkboxes should be selected, but this doesn't happen until  one subcategory checkbox is clicked (like the third child), but the list where the selected checkboxes are stored is populated well.

I tried `this.$forceUpdate()` and even `this.$set()` inside the functions called at click on select All and category title (those with blue background) 
Can somebody please help?

I tried to reproduce it in this fiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/7ox5us6j/58/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<el-checkbox class="panels-name" 
  :value="!!selectedPanels[index+1][item.id].find(i=>i===panels.id)"
  @change="handelAddSample(index+1,item.id,panels.id)"
  :label="panels.id"
  :key="panels.id"
>{{panels.reportable_name}}
</el-checkbox>
```

bind by `:value="!!selectedPanels[index+1][item.id].find(i=>i===panels.id)"`, it worked.

just add it to child

```
     handelAddSample(a,b,id) {
        let m = -1;
        if(!!this.selectedPanels[a][b].find((i,index)=>{if(i===id){m=index;return true}})){
            this.selectedPanels[a][b].splice(m,1); 
        }else {
            this.selectedPanels[a][b].push(id);
        }
        this.$forceUpdate()
      },
```

[new demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7ox5us6j/187/)

Comment: It works at click on the category checkbox, but at click on a child, it doesn't.

Comment: i add it; you can see it in new demo;  
https://jsfiddle.net/7ox5us6j/187/

Comment: Forcing the update did the trick, really annoying to find this...

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be with the chekbox

```
<el-checkbox
  :checked="checkAll[index+1][item.id][n]"
  class="panels-name"
  v-model="selectedPanels[index+1][item.id]"
  @change="handelAddSample()"
  :label="panels.id" :key="panels.id"
>{{panels.reportable_name}}</el-checkbox>
```

this element has both `:checked` and `v-model` defined, which will compete, more importantly though, you're using model on a static data (updating searchList, instead of checkAll). For an element-ui you only use `v-model`, and pass the `checkAll` instead of `searchList`.

```
<el-checkbox
  v-model="checkAll[index+1][item.id][n]"
  class="panels-name"
  @change="handelAddSample()"
  :label="panels.id" :key="panels.id"
>{{panels.reportable_name}}</el-checkbox>
```

another thing you should do is use this.$set when you're updating nested properties

```
  selectAllPanels(index, item) {
    if (this.check[index] === true) {
      this.$set(this.check, index, true) // <--- note use of $set here
    } else {
      this.$set(this.check, index, false) // <--- here
    }
    for (let i = 0; i <= this.panelsCategory[item].length; i++) {
        console.log(this.panelsCategory[item][i])
      if (this.panelsCategory[item][i] !== undefined && this.check[index]) {
        this.$set(this.checkAll[index][item], i, true) // <--- here
        this.checkAllPanel(index, item, i)
      } else {
        if (this.panelsCategory[item][i] !== undefined) {
          this.$set(this.checkAll[index][item], i, false) // <--- and here
          this.checkAllPanel(index, item, i)
        }
      }
    }
    //this.$forceUpdate()  // <--- then you don't need forceUpdate
  },
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to delete the `:checked` property. I tried using this.$set, but it didn't work. Changing the model form `selectedPanels[index+1][item.id]` to `checkAll[index+1][item.id][n]` is not ok, because at click on a subcategory checkbox, it will check not only one checkbox, but all others, which has to happen at click on the category checkbox (that with blue background).